# Check is value iside an object array

Tags: php, arrays

My Array is this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [lc_anuradhapura] => Array
        (
            [0] => attr_balapitiya-boat-rides
            [1] => attr_bird-watching-in-kandalama
        )

    [lc_bentota] => Array
        (
            [0] => attr_city-tour
            [1] => attr_colombo-national-museum
        )

    [lc_colombo] => Array
        (
            [0] => attr_cultural-show
            [1] => attr_cycling
        )

)
```

i need to check 'attr_cycling' is inside the 'lc_colmbo'. but it's need be check dynamically, through a common loop.

Comment: Looks more like PHP ?

Comment: php `is_object()` function ,http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php

Comment: @adeneo—whew! I was thinking "*this ES6 stuff is really getting weird…*". ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var found = false;
loop:
for (var i in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    for (var j = 0; j < obj[i].length; j++) {
      if (obj[i][j] === "attr_cycling") {
        found = true;
        break loop;
      }
    }
  }
}
```